# How to Escape Characters in String Parameters

Tags: c#, vb.net

This is my problem:

VB code

```
dbServerBox.Text = "laptop4\laptop4"
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
sb.Append("Data Source=")
sb.Append(Me.dbServerBox.Text)
sb.Append(";Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=5")

string conn = sb.ToString():
```

the string conn now is

```
"Data Source=laptop4\laptop4;Initial Catalog=TAXIDB;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=5"
```

I have c# class with a method
c# code

```
public PdaServerAysnc(string _conn)
{
string Conn = _conn;
}
```

the string Conn now is

```
"Data Source=laptop4\\laptop4;Initial Catalog=TAXIDB;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=5"
```

If I pass this to a sql client connection the connection string is incorrect.Because it has "\\" as opposed to "\"

I can't find a way to sort this out.

Comment: no it hasn't \\ it has \ (one-backslah) you just escaping the backslash.If you see in the debugger don't worry.the intellitrace window shows the escape character but actually it isn't there.

Comment: Have you actually tried using this connection string?

Comment: It won't connect wrong conn string

Comment: In general, use the [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`-class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the string Conn now is `"Data Source=laptop4\\laptop4;...`

No, it's not. Since backslashes must be escaped in C# strings, the C# debugger *shows* strings as having double backslashes... they're not really there.

Comment: If you want to see the *real* value, use the Text inspector (the magnifying glass icon). The popup window will then show you the string as it exists in memory.